# Error when passing a Variable to an np.where function

Tags: python, macos, numpy, where-clause

I have working code for reading and displaying SEGY seismic data. A functional version is too large to paste here.  The problem I am having is with the following section.

```
    #find traces indices that belong to Inline x
    CXline=self.Line_box.text() #Get chosen line from Gui textbox
    if CXline=="": #If empty, use all inline indices
        inds=np.where(inlines)[0]
    else:    
        inds=np.where(inlines==(CXline))[0] #load data for specific inline indices.
```

If the Line_box (QT textEdit box) is left empty, the 'if' part works as expected and the 'inds' output array is correct and the code continues to run.

If I enter a number (eg 425) into the Line_box, what I want to happen is for that number to be used in the np.where function but it is not working, it just outputs an empty array and the code stops. I also get the following message (although it is the empty array that is causing the crash).

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "/Users/willhutchins/Documents- Offline/Python/Synth_Seismic/SEGY View/SEGY_Viewer.py", line 269
inds=np.where(inlines==(str(CXline)))[0]
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

If I manually type a number into the code as follows, the code runs as expected so it is definitely something to do with how the np.where understands the input from the Line_box. I'm assuming I either have the syntax wrong or need to convert the Line_box input into a different dtype.

```
        else:    
        inds=np.where(inlines==425)[0]
```

Comment: `where` just returns the indices of the True/nonzero elements of its argument.  So you have to first get `inlines==425` or what ever right first.  Explain what `inlines` and `CXline` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie error (long day). It was a dtype conflict. I just needed to convert the incoming Line_box string  to an integer.

```
        else:    
        inds=np.where(inlines==(int(CXline)))[0]
```